# changing notebook page title to bold in Wxpython

Tags: python, wxpython

I have the following code:

```
self.NB = wx.Notebook(self.panel_1, -1, style=0)
self.NB_Partsnote= NB_Parts(self.NB,None,userId)
self.NB_Parts2note = NB_Parts2(self.NB,None,userId)
self.NB.AddPage(self.NB_Partsnote,_("Parts"))
self.NB.AddPage(self.NB_Parts2note ,_("Parts2"))
```

This create the notebook and add 2 tabs.

in Parts2 I have a textctrl with readonly data:

```
self.cellPhone = wx.TextCtrl(self, -1, "", style=wx.TE_READONLY)
```

What I want is when `self.cellPhone` has value then the `Parts2` title of the notebook to be `BOLD`

I tried to do:

```
class NB_Parts2(GeneralPanel):
    def __init__(self,parent,poId,userId, toolbar=None):
    more code...
    if self.cellPhone.GetValue() <> '':
        SetFont(wx.Font(8, wx.FONTFAMILY_DEFAULT,
                             wx.FONTWEIGHT_BOLD, 
                             wx.FONTSTYLE_NORMAL))
```

But this doesn't work. nothing happens. I tried also to remove the condition so it will always be BOLD but still nothing happens.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

When using the native notebook widget a font can be set for all tabs, but not for individual tab.  Calling notebook.SetFont would result in all tabs being bold.

One possible solution is using Images to customize what gets displayed in each tab.

```
import wx

app = wx.App()

frame = wx.Frame(None, size=(600, 600))

# Draw a bitmap image with normal text
notBold = wx.Bitmap(150, 40, depth=32)
dc = wx.MemoryDC()
dc.SetFont(wx.Font(12, wx.FONTFAMILY_DEFAULT,
                   wx.FONTSTYLE_NORMAL, wx.FONTWEIGHT_NORMAL,))

dc.SelectObject(notBold)
dc.Clear()
dc.DrawText("Text not bold", 5, 5)
dc.SelectObject(wx.NullBitmap)

# Draw a bitmap image with bold text
withBold = wx.Bitmap(150, 40)
dc = wx.MemoryDC()
dc.SetFont(wx.Font(12,  wx.FONTFAMILY_DEFAULT,
                   wx.FONTSTYLE_NORMAL, wx.FONTWEIGHT_BOLD,))
dc.SelectObject(withBold)
dc.Clear()
dc.DrawText("Text BOLD", 5, 5)
dc.SelectObject(wx.NullBitmap)


# wx.Notebook needs a wx.ImageList to set images from
# Notice images must be at least the size set by wx.ImageList.__init__
imgList = wx.ImageList(150, 40)
imgList.Add(notBold)
imgList.Add(withBold)


panel = wx.Panel(frame)
notebook = wx.Notebook(panel)
notebook.SetImageList(imgList)


notebook.AddPage(wx.Panel(notebook), "")
notebook.SetPageImage(0, 0)  # notBold
notebook.AddPage(wx.Panel(notebook), "")
notebook.SetPageImage(1, 1)  # withBold

notebook.AddPage(wx.Panel(notebook), "Image not required")

sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
sizer.Add(notebook, proportion=1, flag=wx.EXPAND)
panel.SetSizerAndFit(sizer)

frame.Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Jake’s answer, you may also try FlatNotebook or AuiNotebook to get the effect you are looking for. Docs:

https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/wx.lib.agw.flatnotebook.html#module-wx.lib.agw.flatnotebook

https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/wx.lib.agw.aui.auibook.AuiNotebook.html#wx.lib.agw.aui.auibook.AuiNotebook

Andrea.